# How to enlarge the nvs partition in ESP32-WROOM32 4MB

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32, espressif-idf

I need to enlarge my nvs partition to store more data. Below is my ideal partition constellation:

```
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size, Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,     0x9000,  0x8000,
otadata,  data, ota,     0x11000,  0x2000,
app0,     app,  ota_0,   0x13000, 0x1E0000,
app1,     app,  ota_1,   0x1F3000,0x1E0000,
spiffs,   data, spiffs,  0x3D3000,0x2D000,
```

However, when building, I am getting the following error:

```
Partition app0 invalid: Offset 0x13000 is not aligned to 0x10000
*** [.pio/build/esp32dev/partitions.bin] Error 2
```

Now my questions: Does app0 always have to start from 0x10000?
How can I apply the above partition table?

Using VScode, Platform IO and framework-arduinoespressif32. I do need OTA and my app portions must be at least 0x1E0000 large.

Answer (score 1):

I found messing with Arduino's default NVS partition causes untold issues, and I wanted a really big NVS partition for good wear-levelling with rapidly changing numbers... Since I wasn't using spiffs, my solution was to change spiffs to nvs2 as follows..

```
# Name,   Type, SubType, Offset,  Size,    Flags
nvs,      data, nvs,     0x9000,  0x5000,
otadata,  data, ota,     0xe000,  0x2000,
app0,     app,  ota_0,   0x10000, 0x330000,
app1,     app,  ota_1,   0x340000,0x330000,
nvs2,     data, nvs,     0x670000,0x180000,
```

Now that u have 2 nvs partitions, u can store slowly changing prefs in the small default nvs and rapidly changing ones (like a scope-trace or counters) in the huge nvs2 for best wear-levelling! You can, of course, also split the large upper-area between nvs2 and spiffs if u need to!

Answer (score 0):

See: [Espressif's API guide on partition tables](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/partition-tables.html):

> **Partitions of type app have to be placed at offsets aligned to 0x10000**
> (64 K). If you leave the offset field blank, gen_esp32part.py will
> automatically align the partition. **If you specify an unaligned offset
> for an app partition, the tool will return an error**.

I would try:

- have ota_0 start at 0x20000 and see if you can live with the remaining space, or;
- change your code from needing nvs to use spiffs, or;
- drop using OTA, or;
- see if you can change the CONFIG_PARTITION_TABLE_OFFSET from 0x8000 to earlier. This is where the partition table is stored, and the reason why the table starts at 0x9000. But [here](https://community.platformio.org/t/pio-issues-with-partition-offset/16083) is a guy who had a problem with that in PIO...

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer Gotfredsen - I will try it out in the next couple of days.